# How to smooth a mesh imported in .wrl format?

Tags: mesh, materials, blender-internal-render-engine, polycount

I imported a mesh in .WRL format representing molecules (I did it in PyMol).
This is what I got:
[image]

As you can see, there are **big chunks of triangles** everywhere. They are pretty big and it's not nice to see. Even putting the red material took no effect.

I also tried to export the mesh in .FBX format in Unreal Engine 4, but nothing changed.
Still not sure if it's a rendering configuration problem, or I have to find a way to smooth the mesh adding more polygons.

Is there a way to solve this? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'm fairly new to Blender myself, so take what I say with a grain of salt, but in general, there's two ways to deal with this, depending on what you need the file for.

The easiest way is to just go object mode > select the object (for all objects, just press "A") > right click > shade smooth. That only makes it look more smooth though, it doesn't actually change anything about the file.

To actually change your mesh, use the subdivision surface modifier. In this video, both approaches are explained fairly well:

https://youtu.be/RaT-uG5wgUw?list=PLjEaoINr3zgEq0u2MzVgAaHEBt--xLB6U&t=584

PyMol itself is most likely using some type of modifier/effect when displaying Objects, while the base object has a rather low vertex count.

Answer (score 0):

You need to delete the duplicated vertices. Go <kbd>tab</kbd> into *Edit Mode* then press <kbd>A</kbd> to select all vertices and hit <kbd>M</kbd> to merge vertices. Choose *By Distance*. Follow [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vmyqUagUq4k).

Then <kbd>tab</kbd> to return to *Object Mode* and while object is selected, right click then pick *Shade Smooth*.